# Unix Domain Sockets in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'd like to read messages from a Unix Domain socket (SOCK_STREAM) but I'm having difficulty finding a working example of doing that in Elixir. I've been trying to make it work with the procket library from Erlang, but I've had nothing but trouble.

Can anyone show me a working example of reading from a unix domain socket in Elixir?

Comment: I know you asked about Elixir examples but here's a thread about reading messages from Unix Domain sockets in Erlang http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2009-March/042184.html.  I'd guess the answer is likely to be a custom port in Elixir too.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/awetzel/neovim-elixir/blob/master/lib/link.ex) is a nice example, using [:procket](https://github.com/msantos/procket).

`open` functions get a tuple of file descriptors `{stdin, stdout}` from a connection address, either IPv4, IPv6 or unix domain socket.

EDIT: It's used here to initialize a port, but using `http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/IO.html` it's easy to read from.

Answer (score 2):

There's no support for Unix Sockets in vanilla Erlang nor in Elixir.

Still there are couple of solutions, provided as C-extensions.
One is already mentioned [procket](https://github.com/msantos/procket), other is [afunix](https://github.com/tonyrog/afunix).

I find examples in the `afunix` readme pretty straightforward and easy to brain-translate to Elixir (remember to lowercase the vars and use apostrophes `'` instead of quotes `"` !).

[EDIT]

Erlang project (as long as it's rebar-ized, both above are) can be easily added to your Mix project by adding to deps the following tuple (shamelessly promoting mentioned `afunix` for no reason :) :

`{:afunix,  github: "tonyrog/afunix"}`